# Get values from a specific user - queryset in Django

Tags: django

I stuck with this queryset, no idea how to write it properly. So I'd like to see all related users to this specific user, in other words I have a friend list.

models.py

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friendship_creator_set", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_set", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    friends = Friend...

    context = {
        'friends': friends,
    }

    return render(request, ..., context)
```

How to write queryset to get list of usernames who are firends to specific user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the list of `User`s that are friends with a given user through:

```
friends = User.objects.filter(friendship_creator_set__friend=request.user)
```

(or use a specific user instead of `request.user` if you want to retrieve the friends of another one.)

or if you want to obtain the `User`s that `request.user` considers friends (so the relation in reverse), you can use:

```
friends = User.objects.filter(friend_set__user=request.user)
```

These are the `User` objects. We can also obtain the `Friend` objects, with:

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(friend=request.user)
```

or we can obtain the user names with:

```
usernames = User.objects.filter(
    friendship_creator_set__friend=request.user
).value_list('username', flat=True)
```

Although it is usually better to work with *model* objects, not with the values of that column, since a model attaches special behavior to values. A `User` is more informative than the `username` of a `User`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use `friends = Friend.objects.filter(friend=request.user)` and in pass this to `context`, and in my html I try to print this variable with `{{ friends }}` it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Hiddenguy: well it is probably printed as `<QuerySet [ Friend(1), Friend(25) ]>`, so as a HTML tag, that is then ignored by the browser. You thus should *iterate* over it, and render the `Friend`s, like `{% for friend in friends %} {{ friend.user.username }}{% endfor %}`. Note however that if you use `Friend` objects, this will result in an *N+1* problem.

Comment: Yes I know, and the reason why I tried with `{{ friend }}` instead of the loop is because I got empy Queryset `<QuerySet []>` and that's the point where I' stuck.

Comment: @Hiddenguy: you realize that `Friend` is an *assymetrical* relation: that if *A* is a friend of *B*, *B* is not per se a friend of *A* here. I had the idea that the friendship went from `user` to `friend`, which looks the most reasonable for the given nomenclature.

Comment: I understand. I did something similar to your code, but with this example `friends = Friend.objects.filter(user__username=request.user)`, and when I use the loop in html, I received 4 times of one user. So the question is how to take his `friends`? As I said this loop gives this result `{% for friend in friends %} {{ friend.user.username }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: @Hiddenguy: see edit, but now it looks like you perform a "reverse" lookup.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've been looking for. Then the loop looks like this `{% for friend in friends %}
                {{ friend.username }}
          {% endfor %}</p>`